# Help with bar chart

Tags: biblatex, graphics, graphs, code, programming

I need to make a graph similar to the photo. I have the beginning of the code in LATEX, but it does not work correctly, you also need to add inscriptions like in the photo, you can write in your own language, I can edit it. I really need help.[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, ymax=14, % Устанавливаем минимальное и максимальное значение по оси Y
            ymajorgrids=true, % Включаем сетку по оси Y
            bar width=8pt, % Ширина столбцов
            xlabel={Частота, Гц}, % Подпись оси X
            ylabel={Среднеквадратическое значение напряжения, В}, % Подпись оси Y
            xtick={220,225,...,320}, % Значения по оси X
            xticklabels={220,225,...,320}, % Подписи значений по оси X
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}, % Стиль подписей по оси X
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep=, % Убираем разделитель тысяч
                rotate=90, % Поворачиваем подписи на 90 градусов
                anchor=east % Якорь для поворота
            },
            enlarge x limits=0.05, % Увеличиваем пределы оси X для визуального комфорта
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1} % Расположение легенды
            ]
            
            % Данные графика
            \addplot coordinates {(220,0.5) (225,0.5) (230,0.5) (235,0.5) (240,0.5) (245,0.75) (250,14) (255,0.75) (260,1) (265,1.25) (270,1.5) (275,1.75) (280,2) (285,8) (290,6) (295,4) (300,3) (305,2) (310,1) (315,0.5) (320,0.5)};
            
            % Добавляем пунктирные линии для подгрупп
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:240,0) -- (axis cs:240,14);
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:250,0) -- (axis cs:250,14);
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:290,0) -- (axis cs:290,14);
            
            % Подписи для групп
            \node at (axis cs:245,15) [anchor=north] {Гармоническая подгруппа};
            \node at (axis cs:320,15) [anchor=north] {Интергармоническая группа};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please choose your question titles so they describe the actual problem you face. The purpose of this site is to build a library of knowledge in which future users with the same problem should be able to find the solution. With generic title "Help with ...", they will have a difficult time to find the solution.

Comment: Please also choose your tags more carefully. What does your question have to do with biblatex???

Comment: Would be easier for an international audience to complement your non-english comments by english ones. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it.

I marked the changes with `% <<<` . However, introducing the decorations gives some strange effect on the outer box, which I couldn't resolve. A bypass can be, e.g., to remove the decorations again, and construct those horizontal pathes manually.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}  % <<<
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,width=20cm} % <<<
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}  % <<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[% some styles
        txt/.style={fill=white,anchor=center},
        decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm},
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, ymax=16, % <<< % Устанавливаем минимальное и максимальное значение по оси Y
            ymajorgrids=true, % Включаем сетку по оси Y
            bar width=8pt, % Ширина столбцов
            xlabel={Частота, Гц}, % Подпись оси X
            ylabel={Среднеквадратическое значение напряжения, В}, % Подпись оси Y
            xtick={220,225,...,320}, % Значения по оси X
            xticklabels={220,225,...,320}, % Подписи значений по оси X
            x tick label style={
            rotate=-90,     % <<<
            anchor=east}, % Стиль подписей по оси X
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep=, % Убираем разделитель тысяч
                rotate=90, % Поворачиваем подписи на 90 градусов
                anchor=east % Якорь для поворота
            },
            enlarge x limits=0.05, % Увеличиваем пределы оси X для визуального комфорта
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1} % Расположение легенды
            ]
            
            % Данные графика
           \addplot coordinates {(220,0.5) (225,0.5) (230,0.5) (235,0.5) (240,0.5) (245,0.75) (250,14) (255,0.75) (260,1) (265,1.25) (270,1.5) (275,1.75) (280,2) (285,8) (290,6) (295,4) (300,3) (305,2) (310,1) (315,0.5) (320,0.5)};
            
            % Добавляем пунктирные линии для подгрупп
%            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:240,0) -- (axis cs:240,14);
%            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:250,0) -- (axis cs:250,14);
%            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:290,0) -- (axis cs:290,14);
            
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:237.3,0) -- (axis cs:237.5,14);
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:252.5,0) -- (axis cs:252.5,14);

            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:247.5,0) -- (axis cs:247.5,12);
            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:292.5,0) -- (axis cs:292.5,12);

            % braces, as decorations
            \draw[decorate,dashed] (axis cs:237.5,14) -- (axis cs:252.5,14);
            \draw[decorate,dashed] (axis cs:247.5,12) -- (axis cs:292.5,12);
            
            % Подписи для групп
            \node at (axis cs:245,15) [txt] {Гармоническая подгруппа};
            \node at (axis cs:270,13) [txt] {Интергармоническая группа};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```